# How do I pass down errors object to <Field> component while using a multistep form setup using Formik?

Tags: formik

I have a working example of Formik's multistep wizard form [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvkifl?file=src%2Fmultistep-form%2FMultistepForm.js)

What I'm looking to achieve is to conditionally add a class depending on whether a field has been touched and has errors. I want to have a class that allow me to turn the border color red on an input so it stands out when it's in an error state. Something like this.

```
          <Field
        autoComplete="email"
        component="input"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        type="text"
        className={}
      />
```

But I'm struggling here because I don't seem to have access to the errors object in this setup.